# Update Matplotlib plot using IPython Widgets

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I would like to use IPython widgets to load and plot or update an image in a single matplotlib figure whenever I press a button. I don't want to create more than one figure, just update the existing figure. I tried to solve in a few different ways but haven't had success yet. When I place `plt.figure()` outside the function `loadimg()`, it doesn't plot. I plan to have multiple plots in the notebook for other purpuses, so I'm avoiding to use gca and gcf.

```
def loadimg():
    im = plt.imread(txt.value)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.imshow(im)


txt = widgets.Text(value=str("img.png"), placeholder='', description='File Path:', disabled=False)
bt = mk_btn_file('...', txt)

bt_load = widgets.Button(description="Load")
bt_load.on_click(lambda self : loadimg())

row1 = widgets.HBox((txt,bt))
row2 = bt_load

display(widgets.VBox((row1,row2)))

fig = plt.figure()
```

Another attempt was to use Output(), but for some reason, when I press the button for the second time, it clears the output and plots again twice instead of only once.

```
out = widgets.Output()
def loadimg():
    out.clear_output()
    with out:
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        im = plt.imread(txt.value)
        ax.imshow(im)
        print('Hello')
    display(out)

txt = widgets.Text(value=str("img.png"), placeholder='', description='File Path:', disabled=False)
bt = mk_btn_file('...', txt)

bt_load = widgets.Button(description="Load")
bt_load.on_click(lambda self : loadimg())

row1 = widgets.HBox((txt,bt))
row2 = bt_load

display(widgets.VBox((row1,row2)))
```

Any idea of how I could solve it? Thank you in advance